# inconsistent text sources between the web (using Google Chrome to view sources) and web scraping tools

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am working on web scraping on the Zillow website, and I have tried two Python libraries to get the web texts (using requests and httplib2). I meet inconsistent numbers of cases for sale, due to different text sources between the web (using Google Chrome to view sources) and web scraping tools

My code includes three steps.

1. access the cases by zip codes (like https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/75001_rb/2_p/)
2. get longitude, latitude and zpid (like /homedetails/3756-Park-Pl-Addison-TX-75001/26935870_zpid/)
3. use the zpid to access the detailed information, like https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/3756-Park-Pl-Addison-TX-75001/26935870_zpid/

   ```
   import re

   import httplib2
   http = httplib2.Http()
   status, response = http.request(webpage)
   response=response.decode('utf-8')

   import requests
   headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5)","accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","accept-charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3","accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch","accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",}
   response = requests.get(webpage, headers=headers)
   response=response.text

   webpage='https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/75001_rb/2_p/'
   response = requests.get(webpage, headers=headers)
   response=response.text

   regex_longs='<meta itemprop="longitude" content="(.+?)"></meta></span><div class="zsg-photo-card-caption">'
   pattern_longs = re.compile(regex_longs)
   longs = re.findall(pattern_longs,response1)

   regex_id='></div><a href="(.+?)" class="zsg-photo-card-overlay-link routable hdp-link routable mask hdp-link">'
   pattern_id = re.compile(regex_id)
   ID = re.findall(pattern_id,response1)
   ```

I got 13 cases with longitudes in Google Chrome and from the two python packages, but I only got 12 cases with zpid from the two python packages (the number of zpid in Google Chrome is 13).

Updated: this problem is solved by the selenium package. As Charles Duffy mentioned, DOMs result in differences of text sources between browsers and APIs.

P.S. The issue here may also relate to web parse, as re package is not ideal for web scraping.

Comment: What tools are you using for web scraping? The best ones are headless browsers and browser testing such as selenium, this way you can run JS and get better results.

Comment: Show us some code and we can tell you what's wrong with it. SO tries to discourage "questions" that could have many answers depending on the responders' opinions.

Comment: You could also try [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) another webscraping module which is very useful

Comment: Re: (2), that's to be expected -- your browser's DOM will be *derived from* the original source, but it's not the same as it.

Comment: (btw, even though this isn't shown since the vote went a different way -- I was close-as-too-broad, not close-as-lacking-MCVE; one of the guidelines in the help center is that if one could write a book on a subject, a question about it is too broad, and there literally *are* books on this subject).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are scraping a website that is rendered using **JavaScript** (Dynamic website) that is why you are getting inconsistency between google chrome source code and web scraping tool.

I'd recommend using any one of these for scraping dynamic websites

- [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)
- [Splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)